# How would I read strings and doubles off of a text file while also recording the number of lines in the file?

Tags: c

I am creating a small shop program and am trying to read the catalogue of items that a user can select from, to later add to their cart where they can then purchase these items. I have created a structure for the items which consists of a character array for the name and a double for the cost called "item_t". I am using arrays for both my cart and catalogue of items. I have also created a menu where you can add items to your cart, remove items, view cart, view catalogue and checkout. I would now like to improve the program by being able to read the items for the catalogue off of a text file, and then place them in an array called catalogue. My text file is called "**grcitem**" and is formatted as follows:

Apples 5.00

Oranges 8.00

Bananas 7.00

Mangoes 15.00

Strawberries 10.00

This is the code that I currently have but with the contents of the functions cut out so that it's easier to read. If more information is needed please ask. I am open to formatting my document differently among many other changes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct item
{
   char name[128];
   double cost;
};

typedef struct item item_t;
int addItemToCart(item_t catalogue[], item_t cart[], int itemCount);
int removeItemFromCart(item_t cart[], int itemCount);
char read_char(void);
void print_help(void);
void print_menu(void);
void display_all_items(item_t cart[], int itemCount);
void cost(item_t cart[], int itemCount);
void display_catalogue(item_t catalogue[]);
int read_catalogue(item_t catalogue[]);
int item_count(void);
int main(void)
{
  catalogue_length = int item_count(void);
  item_t catalogue[catalogue_length];
  read_catalogue(catalogue);
  printf("Welcome to the store!\n");
  print_help();
  print_menu();
  int itemCount = 0;
  item_t cart[30];
  char choice = '0';
//I am not sure how to loop this indefinitely so I just have this 
//weird while loop here at the moment and was planning on fixing later
while((choice = read_char())!= '~')
  {
    switch(choice)
    {
      case 'a' :
        //adds item to cart
        print_menu();
        break;

      case 'r' :
        //Removes item from cart
        print_menu();
        break;

      case 'c' :
        //Displays all items in the cart
        print_menu();
        break;

      case 'd' :
        //Displays the catalogue
        print_menu();
        break;

      case 'x' :
        //Displays cart with total cost and then ends program
        return 0;
        break;

      default :
        //prints help menu
        print_menu();
        break;
    }
  }

//Haven't placed all my functions here as it would create too much clutter
int item_count(void)
{
  //I would like to call this function so I can count the 
  //amount of lines in the text file(grcitem) so I can set my catalogue array
  //to be the same length as the number of lines
}

int read_catalogue(item_t catalogue[])
{
  //A function that will record all of the names and costs of the items
  //and place them into the catalogue array
}
```

So I would appreciate any help in creating the two functions at the bottom and any other constructive criticisms anybody might have, and just tell me if you need more detail or I need to change something about my post.

Comment: Does it work if you put the full path there instead of just `"grcitem"`?

Comment: your code doesn't do anything - your `main` function just declares a variable.

Comment: @ChrisTurner the size of the array in `main` is a function call, but the function does not exist.

Comment: Can you please post the actual code that you used when compiling?

Comment: `item_count` or `line_count`? Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `fopen` returns `NULL` if the file could not be opened, that's obviously what happens here. The most common reason for `fopen` returning `NULL` is because the file does not exist. Please tell us where _exactly_  your file is and how you launch your program. Also read the other comments carefully.

Comment: Okay I tried to post a simplified version of my code in a rush and it's obviously a mess that makes no sense. I am going to try fix it up and post something that at least makes some sense. Apologies.

Comment: @ryan_dawson it's OK to post simplified code, it's even a very good idea, but that code must be a [mcve].

Comment: It's now updated hopefully that's better?

Comment: "*help in creating the two functions at the bottom*" there many ways to solve this, so I propose you try to find at least one, and if while trying to make it "work" you are facing **specific** issues, come back here and we happily discuss them with you. As it stands (without proposed code) I feel this question is way to broad.

Answer (score 1):

Only obvious problem I can see with the code is you're seeking to the end of the file with this line

```
fseek (new_file, 0, SEEK_END);
```

and then not seeking back to the start to do the `fscanf`. If you add this line before you do the reading it should work

```
fseek (new_file, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

Comment: Or, for those like me that always hesitate on `fseek` params, there is the [`rewind()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rewind) function

Comment: That's just _one_ of several problems.